# Can Firefox Web Extensions ask for permissions on-demand?

Tags: firefox, browser, permissions, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to have a Firefox browser Web Extension ask for certain permissions only when the user enables specific options in the extension's settings?

I've been reading the developer documentation, and I'm not certain about this.  To see if it's possible, I've also looked for an extension that does this, but have yet to find one, even after experimenting with about 100 different extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see details on this MDN page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions